# How to configure OpenID consumer on SimpleSAMLphp?

Tags: openid, simplesamlphp

I'm trying to configure OpenIDConsumer on SimplesSamlPhp. The repository https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp-module-openid is archived and i don't find any documentation about it.

I'm getting a Not a valid OpenID error.

The origine of this error is that OpenIDConsumer tries to get the key **openid.session**  from the session dataStore but this key doesn't exist in my case (line 24 in SessionStore) :

```
    $session = SimpleSAML_Session::getSessionFromRequest();
    return $session->getData('openid.session', $key);
```

I'm using **simplesamlphp 1.18.7** and the last version of **simplesamlphp-module-openid**.

Anyone has an idea about this problem ?